# Remove 'rel' attributes from the_category() output

Tags: categories, validation, customization, html

I am trying to get the categories associated with a post in it's meta section by using the following code:

```
<div>FILED AS: <span class="gf-post-meta-result"><?php the_category(' &bull; ') 
?></span></div>
```

WordPress is generating the markup as:

```
<div>FILED AS: <span class="gf-post-meta-result">
    <a href="http://localhost/test/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized</a>
</span></div>
```

This part `rel="category tag"` is making my code invalid. W3C validator throws an error saying:

> Bad value category tag for attribute rel on element a: The string category is not a registered keyword or absolute URL. Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.
>
> …w all posts in Uncategorized" rel="category tag">Uncategorized

Any idea how to rectify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter `the_category`, and remove those attributes:

```
add_filter( 'the_category', 't5_remove_cat_rel' );

function t5_remove_cat_rel( $list )
{
    return str_replace(
        array ( 'rel="category tag"', 'rel="category"' ), '', $list
    );
}
```

Comment: any side effect of removing "rel"?

Comment: @t-p Yes, cleaner markup, better [text-to-code-ratio](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/39559/647). :)

Comment: I actually wrote a tutorial featuring similar code over a year ago. That tutorial can be found on [my blog](http://josephleedy.me/blog/make-wordpress-category-list-valid-by-removing-rel-attribute/).